# Woocommerce change shipping tax with hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Right now I have the shipping costs taxes correctly set (e.g. VAT).

But for certain users I must apply another type of tax only for the shipping costs (e.g. VAT + RE). Is there any hook to modify the shipping costs taxes? I have already solved the validation of the user role.

If hook doesn't exist any suggestion is welcome